# convert from string to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm importing a csv file from AWS S3 in AWS Lambdawith below code:

```
file = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
rows = file['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').splitlines(False)
```

I'm getting input in below format :

**data = "a,b,c,d,\"x,y\",e,f"**

and I want output in below format:

```
>>>`>>> df
   0  1  2  3    4  5  6
0  a  b  c  d  x,y  e  f`
```

i have to split data based on ',' but if some thong is between " " they should remain as it is.

**Or if you have any other solution for import csv file from s3 to lambda and converting in Data Frame, Please suggest**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `csv` module

try this,

```
from csv import reader
import pandas as pd
data=["a,b,c,d,\"x,y\",e,f"]
df=pd.DataFrame( list(reader(data)))
print df
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3    4  5  6
0  a  b  c  d  x,y  e  f
```