# Python convert byte string to list of dictionaries based on newline

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, byte

I have a string byte

```
data = b'ra1,rb1,rc1\nra2,rb2,rc2\nra3,rb3,rc3\nra4,rb4,rc4' # No \n at the end
```

The result should be like

```
result = [
{"field1": "ra1", "field2": "rb1", "field3": "rc1"},
{"field1": "ra2", "field2": "rb2", "field3": "rc2"},
{"field1": "ra3", "field2": "rb3", "field3": "rc3"},
{"field1": "ra4", "field2": "rb4", "field3": "rc4"}
]
```

I tried

```
result = csv.DictReader(data, fieldnames=('field1', 'field2', 'field3'))
```

Please note that I'm not dealing with any CSV files here.
I know we need to pass file object as the first parameter to the above DictReader method to get the above result.
Is there any similar in-built method in python 3.6 to achieve my result?
Here I don't want to use loop since my data will be very huge.

Comment: Have a look at this answer, using the csv package's reader for a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53278358/convert-from-string-to-pandas-dataframe

Comment: The size of your data is irrelevant to whether a loop should be used or not.

Comment: What was the problem with the code you’ve tried?

Comment: @sekky, Even I don't want to use pandas package since it is huge in package size and also having lot of depending packages. For this single line, I don't want to  waste 27 MB in my application server.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I'm not handling any CSV files. This is the problem. This DictReader method is available in CSV package.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of lists of all the values by splitting on `\n` and then `,`

Then you can `zip` the keys with each value sublist to create your list of dictionaries

Hence the code will be

```
data = b'ra1,rb1,rc1\nra2,rb2,rc2\nra3,rb3,rc3\nra4,rb4,rc4'
keys = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']

#Create list of lists for values
values  = [ item.split(',') for item in data.decode('utf-8').splitlines() ]
#[['ra1', 'rb1', 'rc1'], ['ra2', 'rb2', 'rc2'], ['ra3', 'rb3', 'rc3'], ['ra4', 'rb4', 'rc4']]

#Create result dictionary by zipping keys and values
result = [dict(zip(keys, value)) for value in values]
print(result)
```

And the output will be

```
[{'field1': 'ra1', 'field2': 'rb1', 'field3': 'rc1'}, 
{'field1': 'ra2', 'field2': 'rb2', 'field3': 'rc2'}, 
{'field1': 'ra3', 'field2': 'rb3', 'field3': 'rc3'}, 
{'field1': 'ra4', 'field2': 'rb4', 'field3': 'rc4'}]
```

Comment: Is there any python in-built method to achieve this without these many loops? Since my data is very large, this will take twice the time.

Comment: Well you need to go through all items at0least once to process them, which the for loop does (it covers all items in one go, you can see the output of values list for the same), so you cannot avoid it @CMY All other solutions need to do it as well

Comment: Hi @CMY If you have any more questions let me know :) Otherwise if the answer helped you , please consider marking it as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer :) I would also suggest you to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd, io
data = b'ra1,rb1,rc1\nra2,rb2,rc2\nra3,rb3,rc3\nra4,rb4,rc4'
names = {0:'fields1',1:'fields2',2:'fields3'}

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode('utf8')),header=None).rename(names,axis=1).to_dict('records')

[{'fields1': 'ra1', 'fields2': 'rb1', 'fields3': 'rc1'},
 {'fields1': 'ra2', 'fields2': 'rb2', 'fields3': 'rc2'},
 {'fields1': 'ra3', 'fields2': 'rb3', 'fields3': 'rc3'},
 {'fields1': 'ra4', 'fields2': 'rb4', 'fields3': 'rc4'}]
```